# Firemonkey -> Webbrowser - disable scrolling possibility

Tags: scroll, firemonkey, twebbrowser

Does anyone know, how to disable scrolling possibility of Webbrowser Control on Firemonkey iOS / Android application?
My goal is to get absolutely static element that will not react on touches and so on.

regards
M.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting its `HitTest` property to **False**? That way, it shouldn't react to the mouse at all.